# Intercommunication between Python MPI master and C MPI worker?

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to write an MPI worker in C that will communicate with the MPI master, written in python. The master will send out scatters and gathers, and the C worker should receive those and return variables via gather. The problem is, I'm having trouble successfully writing the worker file.

(The reason the worker is in C is because this code is a skeleton to wrap around preexisting python and C programs.)

Here is the code I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

MPI_Comm comm;
MPI_Comm_get_parent(&comm);

int myid, world_size, size;
int root = 0;
int* endloop = malloc(sizeof(int));
int nelements1 = 1E3;
int nelements2 = 1E6;
float* input = malloc(sizeof(float) * nelements1);
float output[nelements2];

int randomarray(){
        float array[nelements2];
        srand(time(NULL));
        for( i = 0; i < nelements2; i++ ){
                array[i] = rand() % 0 + 1E6;
        }

        return array;

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
MPI_Comm_remote_size(comm, &size);

output = randomarray();

MPI_Scatter(endloop, 1, MPI_INT, root, comm);

while ( endloop[0] < 1) {
        MPI_Barrier(comm);
        MPI_Scatter(input, nelements1, MPI_FLOAT, root, comm);
        MPI_Barrier(comm);
        MPI_Gather(output, nelements2, MPI_FLOAT, root, comm);
        MPI_Scatter(endloop, 1, MPI_INT, root, comm);
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

And the error output when I attempt to compile is:

```
maddie@exo:~/code/bart_commloop$ mpicc worker.c -o worker
worker.c:5:21: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
worker.c:9:16: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
worker.c:9:1: error: initializer element is not constant
worker.c:12:1: error: initializer element is not constant
worker.c:13:7: error: variably modified ‘output’ at file scope
worker.c: In function ‘randomarray’:
worker.c:18:7: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)
worker.c:18:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
worker.c:19:21: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
worker.c:22:2: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
worker.c:22:2: warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]
worker.c:28:8: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float[1]’ from type ‘int’
worker.c:30:1: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘MPI_Scatter’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1197:20: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
worker.c:30:1: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘MPI_Scatter’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1197:20: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘MPI_Comm’
worker.c:30:1: error: too few arguments to function ‘MPI_Scatter’
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1197:20: note: declared here
worker.c:34:2: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘MPI_Scatter’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1197:20: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
worker.c:34:2: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘MPI_Scatter’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1197:20: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘MPI_Comm’
worker.c:34:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘MPI_Scatter’
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1197:20: note: declared here
worker.c:36:2: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘MPI_Gather’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1058:20: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
worker.c:36:2: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘MPI_Gather’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1058:20: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘MPI_Comm’
worker.c:36:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘MPI_Gather’
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1058:20: note: declared here
worker.c:37:2: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘MPI_Scatter’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1197:20: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
worker.c:37:2: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘MPI_Scatter’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1197:20: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘MPI_Comm’
worker.c:37:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘MPI_Scatter’
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1197:20: note: declared here
worker.c:40:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

The issue seems to be the formatting of my MPI calls, but I'm not sure what to fix there.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Lots of problems in your code. In function `randomarray()` for instance, `i` is not defined, you need an additional bracket `}` at the end of the function, after `return`. And `float array[nelements2];` create a local array of `nelements2`...which will be deleted at `return`. Use something like `float *array =malloc(sizeof(float)*nbelement2);` if you wish to access array's elements outside of function `randomarray()`. And don't forget to `free()` the memory : if you call `malloc` three times, you should call `free` three times... What does `rand() % 0` mean ? Read errors and warns!Bye, Francis

Comment: You seem to be writing your C code as if you are writing in Python. Executable statements in C have to be gathered in functions. You cannot simply place a function call like your call to `MPI_Comm_get_parent()` or an assignment with a function call like calling `malloc()` at the global level. You cannot also declare a function inside another function.

Comment: @Hristo This was an embarrassing mistake to make, I was writing it very much like Python (I've been using Python a lot of late, much more than C) and I got it working.